# Why is my Unity scene prefab auto-changing?

Tags: unity, gameobject

I have some prefabs which are instantiated in game. There are some attributes of prefabs such as size(width, height), text string and color which are changed from code. Well, it is working fine. However, some prefabs changed attributes are being applied permanently.

For example, one prefabs color is changed to red while playing the game. Then, I stop the game using the Editor's "Play" button, and if run the game again, that prefab is still instantiated with the red color.

It happens when I stop the game in the middle of running from the Editor, and the game object in the scene Hierarchy replaces the main game object in the prefab folder.

Why is my Unity scene prefab auto-changing?

Comment: Changes made during play should not do what you are describing. It might be helpful to see your code that is instantiating the object and changing the color.

Comment: Yes, it should be. I have an array that keeps reference of my folder prefabs. Using the array I instantiate objects. I always do this, never faced such problem :(

Comment: https://ideone.com/QKUKxB
This is the part of Instantiating cards. Here the changed attributes are applied to the folder prefabs too. I don't know why is it happening. Is it because of "ref" parameter ?

Comment: Interesting. You are passing by reference using `ref`. I've never done this before in Unity for prefabs but did a test and it leads to changes saving within the prefab folder even after "play" stops. I am using unity 5.5.0f3. If you don't want the changes to save don't use keyword `ref`.

Comment: for further notes on `ref` this explains why that would happen: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx

Comment: Yes. That's it. After you said to review the code, that ref keyword hit my brain. It is now working, I see. Ohh!! What a dumb thing to do. Lesson learned- "Never use ref array to instantiate prefabs" :) Thanks friend.

Comment: FYI : this also happens after running the game in a device ;)

Comment: We would need to see your code. It sounds like your logic directly targets the asset, which would have the above results.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was passing the GameObjects to a function by reference. In that I function several objects are instantiated and changed according to logic. As a reference of main GameObject was instantiated and Changed, it also changed the folders' prefabs.
Now, I've declared a Global array and am not passing any parameter to that function. Instantiating direct from that Global array solved the problem.
Thanks to @Tartle Wizard

Comment: No reason to use a global array, just pass the regular array into the function but don't use the `ref` keyword. Usage of the `ref` keyword is extremely rare overall.